# Theme issue on an ListActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListActivity on wich I apply a light theme using the manifest.

The theme is defined as follow

```
    <style
    name="Theme.Light"
    parent="android:Theme"
>
    <item
        name="android:windowBackground"
    >@android:color/background_light</item>
</style>
```

The idea is to make the ListActivity white instaid of the default black color.

The list is showing white as expected but it turn black as soon as I scroll it.
It turn back white when I stop scrolling.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

Comment: "To fix this issue, all you have to do is either disable the cache color hint optimization, if you use a non-solid color background, or set the hint to the appropriate solid color value. You can do this from code (see setCacheColorHint(int)) or preferably from XML, by using the android:cacheColorHint attribute. To disable the optimization, simply use the transparent color #00000000."

Comment: getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE) works greate. Tks